# Usando Animate.css com hover

Tags: css3, jquery-animate, animate.css

***DESCRIÇÃO:***
Estou querendo usar o **[Animate.css](https://github.com/daneden/animate.css)** no meu projeto, mas estou meio perdido, não entendo nada de jQuerry.

***PROBLEMA:***
Fiz o passo passo assim como manda no GitHub porém não funciona, sei que está faltando algo mas não sei como proceder.

- Tenho o css importado no meu código
- Os objetos a serem animados já estão com suas marcações feitas

mas tenho algumas dúvidas, tipo:

- Onde coloco esse código que é fornecido no tutorial do github? `$('#yourElement').addClass('animated bounceOutLeft');`, coloco ele dentro de uma tag script, sem nenhum `Function`? e Se tiver functoin, qual função eu chamo?
- Como eu faço pra que essa função de animar seja ativada ao dar hover?

Segue link no **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/viniciusColares/sk9za5tr/)**
Obs: Não consegui anexar o animated.css via cdn

Comment: Pode colocar o seu código num jsFiddle e explicar o que quer fazer de animação e com que elemento? assim percebemos melhor o seu problema...

Comment: Então Vinicius. Eu acho que como é elemento do Jquery, deve-se colocar em uma function. Tente colocar e veja se funciona. Se não, poste do jsFiddle pro pessoal ajudar !

Comment: Pergunta editada com o link pra o fiddle

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Como é uma animação, o legal é que ele apareça quando um evento acontecer, por isso que no repositório git do Animate.css tem o exemplo:

```
$('#yourElement').addClass('animated bounceOutLeft');
```

Ou seja, você vai executar essa linha quando um evento acontecer.
Como você solicitou que o evento seja de  **hover** esta ai o codigo para ser colocado dentro de uma tag *script*:

```
<script>
    $('#flipCard')
      .mouseover(function(){
        $('#flipCard').addClass('animated flipInX');  
      })
      .mouseout(function(){
        $('#flipCard').removeClass('animated flipInX');  
      });
</script>
```

Esse trecho de código adiciona a classe quando passa o mouse em cima e remove classe quando o mouse sai.

O efeito utilizado foi o flipInX. Mas tem outros como flipInY, flipOutX, flipOutY.

A velocidade da animação pode ser definida em um css:

```
#flipCard {
 -vendor-animation-duration: 3s;
 -vendor-animation-delay: 2s;
 -vendor-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}
```

É só trocar o *vendor* pelo prefixo que você quer (webkit, moz, o)

Segue o [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/sk9za5tr/2/).